# Adrress is 0 bytes after a block of size and adrees is not stack'd,malloc'd or free'd

Tags: c

So i am trying to run the following program but when i try to insert a value in the skip-list i get a segmatation fault. My goal is to insert all values in the skip list sorted.

```
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int x;
  record *ptrs[5];
  int i;

  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ptrs[i] = malloc(sizeof(record));
  }
  node_ptr skip_list = creat_skip_list();

  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ptrs[i] = malloc(sizeof(record));
    scanf("%d", &x);
    ptrs[i] -> x = x;
    insert_skip_list(skip_list, x, ptrs[i]);

  }
```

My code for the skip list is the following.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "skip_list.h"
#include "test_strc.h"  

typedef struct node {
  int key;
  record *ptr;
  node_ptr forward[MaxLevel];
} node;


node_ptr creat_skip_list() {
  node_ptr head;
  node_ptr last;
  int i;

  head=malloc(sizeof(node));
  last=malloc(sizeof(node));

  for ( i = 0; i < MaxLevel; i++) {
    head->forward[i]=last;
    last->forward[i]=NULL;
  }
  head->ptr = malloc(sizeof(record));
  last->ptr = malloc(sizeof(record));
  last->key=MaxValue+1;
  return head;
};


int randomLevel() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  return rand()%(MaxLevel-1);
}

node_ptr makeNode (int lvl, int searchKey, record* newValue) {
  node_ptr temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
  temp->key = searchKey;
  temp -> ptr = newValue;
  return temp;
}


void insert_skip_list(node_ptr head,int searchKey, record* newValue) {
  printf("asdasd\n" );
  node_ptr update[MaxLevel];
  node_ptr temp=head;
  int i;
  for ( i = MaxLevel; i >= 0; i--) {
    while (temp->forward[i]->key < searchKey) {
      temp=temp->forward[i];
    }
    update[i]=temp;
  }
  temp=temp->forward[0];
  if (temp->key==searchKey)
    temp->ptr = newValue;  
  else {
    int lvl=randomLevel();
    printf("lvl is %d\n", lvl);
    temp=makeNode(lvl,searchKey,newValue); //creates node
    for ( i = 0; i < lvl; i++) {
      temp->forward[i] = update[i]->forward[i];
      update[i]->forward[i] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

The struct recored only contains an int field named x. Valgrind is giving me the following message

```
 ==5124== Invalid read of size 8
==5124==    at 0x400A25: insert_skip_list (skip_list.c:55)
==5124==    by 0x4007E0: main (test_skip.c:23)
==5124==  Address 0x51e02d0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 176 alloc'd
==5124==    at 0x4C28C20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==5124==    by 0x400898: creat_skip_list (skip_list.c:20)
==5124==    by 0x400766: main (test_skip.c:16)
==5124== 
==5124== Invalid read of size 4
==5124==    at 0x400A29: insert_skip_list (skip_list.c:55)
==5124==    by 0x4007E0: main (test_skip.c:23)
==5124==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5124== 
==5124== 
==5124== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5124==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==5124==    at 0x400A29: insert_skip_list (skip_list.c:55)
==5124==    by 0x4007E0: main (test_skip.c:23)
```

What could cause this? Because as it seems i have alocated every block i am going to access. MaxValue is 200 and MaxLevel is 20.

Comment: In `main` you are allocating `ptrs` twice, leaking memory.

Comment: i removed the first allocation but i still get a segmatation fault

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));
  return rand() % (MaxLevel - 1);` likely generates the same random number as `srand()` is repeatedly called with the same time stamp.  Beter to call `srand()` once.

Comment: `insert_skip_list` is not updating the pointer passed, nor returning the new pointer. And please do not `typedef` pointers.

Comment: Recommend dropping the C++ tag before someone charges in screaming that you shouldn't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: Another good reason to drop the unrelated c++ tag is that the provided code isn't c++.

Answer (score 1):

This is your error:

```
for ( i = MaxLevel; i >= 0; i--) {
    while (temp->forward[i]->key < searchKey) {
```

If I want to go backwards, I usually do it this way:

```
for (i = MaxLevel; i--; ) {
```

this has the advantage, that the first access of array[i] doesn't go beyond the array. That's what valgrind detects here. Also, this way i can be unsigned - in your code, it must be signed because otherwise, i >= 0 would always be true.

Comment: actually the problem was that i started from the loop from MaxLevel instead of maxlevel-1

Comment: Your error was that you started from MaxLevel and then didn't decrement one way or the other. There are many solutions to the problem, some are better, some are worse. I showed you one, that will prevent you from ever doing this kind of error again. But you don't have to take this solution. Anyways: If my answer helped you, please accept it.